# Django return field for each model object

Tags: django

I have two models `Game` and `People`. I'm trying to iterate through the People model & return a single CharField for each value that people has & save their score with their name to the `Game` when creating the game. (Don't want name to be a field, just save with the score).

The error I'm currently getting with this is the following: `no such column: home_game.score`

```py
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Game Model:**

```py
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField(verbose_name="Details/Description", blank=False)
    for each in People.objects.all():
        score = models.CharField(verbose_name=each.title, max_length=4)
```

```
class GameCreateview(CreateView):
    model = Game
    fields = ['name', 'details', 'people']
    success_url = 'home/game/game_details.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here doesn't make sense:

```py
for each in People.objects.all():
    score = models.CharField(verbose_name=each.title, max_length=4)
```

Firstly even if the loop works there would only be one score field in the end. Next a Django model is the reflection of a Database table. Ever heard of a table having an arbitrary number of columns (atleast a good normalized table)? No right? Since multiple `People` can be a part of a `Game` and have scores, you should have another table that reflects this relationship. Also to make querying easier use this table with a [`ManyToManyField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) as the `through` model:

```py
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField(verbose_name="Details/Description", blank=False)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(
        People,
        through='PeopleGame',
        related_name='games'
    )

class PeopleGame(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Game: {self.game.title}, Person: {self.person}, Score: {self.score}"
```

> **Note**: Model names should ideally be singular, so use `Person` instead of <s>`People`</s>.

Comment: This isn't showing the error any more and is showing the `People` values, Thanks!! I have another question if you can answer it, how can I show the `score` CharFiled in the Game View? It's only showing the `People` name's but no where to enter the score.

Comment: I have updated my question with my `CreateView`

Comment: @user that is another question, you should ask a new question for that.